# Why is Decimal described as fixed point?

Tags: .net

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> A decimal number is a signed,
>   fixed-point value consisting of an
>   integral part and an optional
>   fractional part. The integral and
>   fractional parts consist of a series
>   of digits that range from zero to nine
>   (0 to 9), separated by a decimal point
>   symbol.

I thought it was a [floating point number with base 10.](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the version of the Framework the description changes:

With 4.0

> A decimal number is a floating-point
>   value that consists of a sign, a
>   numeric value where each digit in the
>   value ranges from 0 to 9, and a
>   scaling factor that indicates the
>   position of a floating decimal point
>   that separates the integral and
>   fractional parts of the numeric value.

I'll say it's sloppy editing of the 1.1 version.

And even in 1.1 in the next paragraph it's written:

> The binary representation of an
>   instance of Decimal consists of a
>   1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number,
>   and a scaling factor used to divide
>   the 96-bit integer and specify what
>   portion of it is a decimal fraction.
>   The scaling factor is implicitly the
>   number 10, raised to an exponent
>   ranging from 0 to 28.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it *is* a floating point number. That's very old documentation - it was fixed in the [.NET 2.0 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

(It's unclear whether this was due to me submitting a correction or whether other people had as well. I do remember having to justify my position time and time again, where I thought it was pretty clear - if `Decimal` was a fixed point type, why did each value include an exponent? I also remember having arguments in C# newsgroups about this, where people were clinging to the documentation as evidence that it really *was* a fixed point type. Oh well.)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because you're looking at the .NET 1.1 version of Decimal.  [The 3.5 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) states:

> A decimal number is a floating-point
>   value that consists of a sign, a
>   numeric value where each digit in the
>   value ranges from 0 to 9, and a
>   scaling factor that indicates the
>   position of a floating decimal point
>   that separates the integral and
>   fractional parts of the numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the documentation. The more recent documentation states that [`A decimal number is a floating-point value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx).

Comment: I answered this question twice? :)

Comment: hm, am I talking with myself? :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the documentation. You're reading the version for .NET 1.1 (which is like 10 years old). If you read the [latest version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=VS.100).aspx) you'll see it has been fixed.